# Passing a delegate reference to another class so that one subscriber can listen to multiple publishers?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I'm getting my head around more complex uses of the event/delegate system, and have a use case that I can't find a solution for.

Say I've got two classes which both handle objects that inherit from the same base class:

```
public class VegetableStore {
    List<VegType> vegtypes;
}
public class MeatStore {
    List<MeatType> meatTypes;
}
// MeatType and VegType both extend abstract class FoodType
```

In a separate class, I want to listen for whenever EITHER a new VegType is added to VegetableStore, or a new MeatType is added to MeatStore.

Now, the "easy" way to do it seems to just be something like this:

```
public class VegetableStore {
        List<VegType> vegtypes;
        public delegate void VegTypeAddedEventHandler(VegType vegType, bool added);
        public event VegTypeAddedEventHandler VegTypeAdded;

        //...
        protected virtual void OnVegTypeAdded(VegType vegType, bool added) {}
}
public class MeatStore {
        List<MeatType> meatTypes
        public delegate void MeatTypeAddedEventHandler(MeatType meatType, bool added);
        public event MeatTypeAddedEventHandler MeatTypeAdded;

        //...
        protected virtual void OnMeatTypeAdded(MeatType meatType, bool added) {}
}
```

And then in my listener class...

```
vegStore.VegTypeAdded += OnFoodTypeAdded;
meatStore.MeatTypeAdded += OnFoodTypeAdded;

void OnFoodTypeAdded(FoodType foodType, bool added) {}
```

This feels a lot more messy than it could be though.

What I'd like to do is have some kind of "parent" delegate, such as `FoodTypeAddedEventHandler(object source, EventArgs e)`
And then be able to automatically subscribe any events that subscribe to this event, to subscribe to events from both Meat and Veg, such that I an intermediate eventmanager class can contain

```
public event FoodTypeAddedEventHandler FoodTypeAdded
{
    add
    {
        vegStore.VegTypeAdded += value;
        meatStore.MeatTypeAdded += value;
    {
    remove
    {
        vegStore.VegTypeAdded -= value;
        meatStore.MeatTypeAdded -= value;
    }
}
```

The trouble is. vegStore and meatStore don't have a delegate of type FoodTypeAddedHandler, so this results in a type error.

Is there a practical way to go about this?  Can't seem to find a reasonably straight forward solution to this problem, but I feel like there must be one.  Or, should I just KISS it?

Comment: I'd start off by removing your specific delegate types - they're not giving you any benefit over just using `EventHandler`, which has exactly the same signature. When you start using `EventHandler` instead, the problem should go away (I suspect, anyway - that's just via inspection).

Comment: My example wasn't clear, as I do actually use custom params - will tidy up.  You're right that EventHandler would otherwise solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generic delegate like this:

```
delegate void FoodTypeAddedEventHandler<in T>(T meatType, bool added) where T : FoodType;
```

Then instead of `VegTypeAddedEventHandler` you have `FoodTypeAddedEventHandler<VegType>` and instead of `MeatTypeAddedEventHandler` you have `FoodTypeAddedEventHandler<MeatType>`. Finally instead of `FoodTypeAddedEventHandler` you have `FoodTypeAddedEventHandler<FoodType>`. After this modifications, your "combined" event handler will compile fine:

```
public event FoodTypeAddedEventHandler<FoodType> FoodTypeAdded
{
    add
    {
        vegStore.VegTypeAdded += value;
        meatStore.MeatTypeAdded += value;
    {
    remove
    {
        vegStore.VegTypeAdded -= value;
        meatStore.MeatTypeAdded -= value;
    }
}
```

Alternatively - just remove all your delegate types and use `Action<FoodType, bool>`, `Action<VegType, bool>` and `Action<MeetType, bool>`. Then your code will also compile fine.

That works because both custom delegate has its first type parameter (`T`) contravariant (`in` modifier). That allows it to accept arguments of derived types (so, delegate `FoodTypeAddedEventHandler<FoodType>` can accept signatures where first parameter is not exactly `FoodType` but any derived type (such as `VegType`). The same works with `Action` because in `Action` all type arguments are also contravariant (declared with `in` modifier). More information about variance in delegates you can read in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates).

Comment: That won't work as written, because `vegStore.VegTypeAdded` won't be compatible with `FoodTypeAddedEventHandler<FoodType>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet why is that? I tried and it compiles fine (though didn't try to run). Note I said to change all delegate types, including vegStore.VegTypeAdded.

Comment: @JonSkeet maybe you miss that both VegType and MeatType inherit from the same class FooType? This is not shown in OP code, but mentioned in comment in that code.

Comment: That wouldn't let you subscribe to the event though - you'd need the generic variance in the other direction. Put it this way: if the event is raised with a `MeatType` value, how do you expect the `vegStore.VegTypeAdded` handlers to accept that value?

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't expect that, but I don't see how it's possible. `FoodTypeAdded` event is not invocable, you can only subscribe\unsubscribe to it (and OP doesn't need to invoke it anyway, only subscribe). Only `VegTypeAdded` (of type `FoodTypeAddedEventHandler<VegType>`) and `MeatTypeAdded` (of type `FoodTypeAddedEventHandler<MeatType>`) can be invoked. I don't see how you can subscribe to VegTypeAdded with delegate which first parameter is `MeatType` with given code. You can subsribe with either `VegType` or with `FoodType` (via `FoodTypeAdded` pseudo event).

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'd been looking at it in entirely the opposite direction. I do apologise.

Comment: This looks like it's going in the right direction, but the question now becomes:  how does VegStore and MeatStore reference the delegate FoodTypeAddedEventHandler<FoodType>?

Is standard practice to just define the delegate outside of a class, in some namespce, so that it can be accessed from any other class?  Or should I be passing it around somehow?

Comment: @Cerzi I'd say standard practice is to just use Action. If you don't like it (that's fine) - then declare delegate type where you see fit: people do that both in namespace and inside class. I prefer namespace.

Comment: Will potentially want multiple subscribers to "FoodTypeAdded", however - would Action still be appropriate for what is essentially an event management system?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Cerzi Action is just another delegate type, so it's appropriate anywhere custom delegate type is. Drawback is Action delegate type parameters have meaningless names (agr1, arg2) etc, so custom delegate type might be better for readability and documentation. For example EventAdded(int eventId, int eventType) might be more readable than Action<int, int>. But benefit is everyone knows what Action is. And for custom delegate type one might need to lookup what exactly are expected parameters. Compare EventAdded (no idea what is this) vs Action<int,int> (signature is clear).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - think I'll stick with delegate for now just for clarity's sake as it's working fine, plus I'll likely end up with a lot of different delegates in this project so will be important to keep things readable.  Cheers